# C programming project

Tags: c, file-io

In my project I have to read two files with integers and combine them into one output file in ascending order.  I'm having a really hard time with this.
Here is some fragment code I'v written, but it doens't work.  Btw I can't use arrays.

```
firstNext = fgetc(input);
secondNext = fgetc(second_input);

fscanf(second_input, "%d", &secondNumber);
fscanf(input, "%d", &firstNumber);              

while(firstNext != EOF && secondNext != EOF)
{   
    if(firstNumber < secondNumber)
    {
        fprintf(output, "%d\n", firstNumber);
        fscanf(input, "%d", &firstNumber);
        firstNext = fgetc(input);
    }

    if(secondNumber < firstNumber)
    {
        fprintf(output, "%d\n", secondNumber);
        fscanf(second_input, "%d", &secondNumber);
        secondNext = fgetc(second_input);   
    }
...
}
```

Sample Input and Output

```
File1
1
5
10
15

File2
2
4
6
8

Output
1
2
4
5
6
8
10
15
```

Comment: I am editing the question with a sample input and output, based on my understanding.  Please correct it if it is wrong.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how can I make this work, I've been at it for HOURS.

Comment: Are the input files sorted?

Comment: The problem is the `fgetc`s.. get rid of them and see what happens. and check the `feof(first)` and `feof(second_input)`

Comment: I forgot to add that, yes they are sorted

Comment: I tried the feof and got rid of the fgetc, it's still printing one less number than before it reaches the end of at least one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *input;
    FILE *second_input;
    int firstNumber;
    int secondNumber;

    input = fopen("file1", "r");
    second_input = fopen("file2", "r");

    fscanf(input, "%d", &firstNumber);
    fscanf(second_input, "%d", &secondNumber);

    while(!feof(input) || !feof(second_input))
    {
        if(firstNumber < secondNumber || feof(second_input))
        {
            printf("%d\n", firstNumber);
            if(!feof(input))
            {
                fscanf(input, "%d", &firstNumber);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d\n", secondNumber);
            if(!feof(second_input))
            {
                fscanf(second_input, "%d", &secondNumber);
            }
        }

        if(feof(input) && !feof(second_input))
        {
            printf("%d\n", secondNumber);
            fscanf(second_input, "%d", &secondNumber);
        }
    }

    fclose(input);
    fclose(second_input);
}
```

Comment: Very good thanks!  It doesn't print the final value from the remaining file, though, but I think I can figure it out from here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get an ascending sorted list of all the numbers into the output file, then you should probably try reading the two lists into separate arrays, sort them individually and then merge the two sorted lists into a single array and then write this list to the output file.

If the input files are already sorted then a simple merge would do the trick. And the `fgetc` wont work i believe. `fgetc` reads a single character from the file. So if the number has more than one digit, it fails. You should probably read each line as a whole into a `char[]` and then use `atoi()` or similar functions before the comparison.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I can't use arrays

Comment: Why not use arrays? Can you explain a bit?

Comment: It's a school project, my teacher says no arrays for this one.

Comment: See the answer by Kinjal Dixit. It doesnt use arrays and eliminates fgetc()

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *combine(FILE *f1, FILE *f2){
    static int num1, num2;
    static int f1_stat, f2_stat;

    if(f1_stat != EOF && f1_stat == 0)//0:used, 1:unused
        f1_stat = fscanf(f1, "%d", &num1) < 1 ? EOF : 1;
    if(f2_stat != EOF && f2_stat == 0)
        f2_stat = fscanf(f2, "%d", &num2) < 1 ? EOF : 1;
    if(f1_stat == EOF)
        return (f2_stat == EOF) ? NULL  : (f2_stat = 0, &num2);
    else
        return (f2_stat == EOF) ? (f1_stat = 0, &num1) : (num1 < num2) ? (f1_stat = 0, &num1) : (f2_stat = 0, &num2);
}

int main(){
    FILE *file1, *file2, *output;
    file1 = fopen("file1.txt", "r");
    file2 = fopen("file2.txt", "r");
    output = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    int *num;
    while(NULL!=(num=combine(file1, file2))){
        fprintf(output, "%d\n", *num);
    }
    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);
    fclose(output);
    return 0;
}
```